# How to enqueue a batch job conditionally

Tags: c#, hangfire

I am breaking up a monolithic class into more re-entrant jobs using Batch jobs in Hangfire Pro.

I want to queue different jobs in Hangfire depending on the outcome of my data checks (e.g if it's successful then continue manipulating the data, if it fails then send some information to the users and update the status to failed).

My code currently looks something like this:

```
//previous batch jobs running here
var parameters = GetParameters();
var importJob = BatchJob.AwaitBatch(previousJob, j =>
{
   j.Enqueue<ImportJob>(job => job.LoadData(parameters));
});
BatchJob.AwaitBatch(importJob, stuff =>
{
   stuff.Enqueue<OtherStuffJob>(job => job.DoTheOtherStuff(parameters));
});
```

I'd like to break it down into something of the form:

```
//previous batch jobs running here
var parameters = GetParameters();
var importJob = BatchJob.AwaitBatch(previousJob, j =>
{
   j.Enqueue<ImportJob>(job => job.LoadData(parameters));
});
BatchJob.AwaitBatch(importJob, stuff =>
{
   var dataIsGood = Checker.DoDataCheck(parameters);
   if (dataIsGood)
   {
      stuff.Enqueue<OtherStuffJob>(job => job.DoTheOtherStuff(parameters));
   }
   else
   {
      stuff.Enqueue<RejectFileJob>(job => job.HandleRejection(parameters));
   }
});
```

I took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151200/hangfire-how-to-enqueue-a-job-conditionally) but their problem was around making sure there were no duplicate jobs from multiple entrance paths.

I'm struggling to find documentation on whether  `dataIsGood` would be evaluated at runtime or whether all jobs would be queued when the batch is called.

Is anyone able to enlighten me as to which would happen?

**EDIT**

So it turns out that this part:

`var dataIsGood = Checker.DoDataCheck(parameters);
   if (dataIsGood)`

gets evaluated while the previous batch jobs are still running, which means that the information that the checker needs is not available to it.

In theory I could resolve the issue by moving the logic down a level into the job itself, but that would mean then either:

- breaking the logic flow of what jobs would be queued dependent on the outcome of the checks.
  OR
- having batch jobs being called from within the job class (which seems wrong).

Which is the lesser of two evils, or can anyone see an alternative way around this?

Comment: Basically the stuff that you are trying to do should work well (shown in your code), as I don't see anything wrong in that. I have not tried it though. Have you got a chance to try it by yourself and see??

Comment: You must be able to debug through this code and check the execution OR you can query Hangfire.Jobs table to see, what jobs have been added/running/completed

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)